# Why is it necessary X and Y beeing bounded when having same moments to be equal

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

> Let $X,Y$ random variables in $[0,1]$ with $E(X^n)=E(Y^n) \,\forall n\in \mathbb N$. I want to show $X\overset{d}{=} Y$.

$$E(e^{itX})=\int\sum \frac{(itx)^k}{k!}dF_X\overset{dom. conv.}{=}\sum\int\frac{(itx)^k}{k!}dF_x=\sum\frac{(it)^k}{k!}\int x^kdF_x\overset{EX^n=EY^n}{=}\sum\frac{(it)^k}{k!}\int x^kdF_Y=\dots=E(e^{itY})$$

> I am aware of the fact $EX^n=EY^n$ does not imply $X\overset{d}{=}Y$ in general. I did not use that X and Y are bounded, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to justify interchange of integral and sum. In this case $\int \sum |\frac {(itx)^{k}} {k!}|d_F(x) \leq e^{|t|}$ so we can use Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: you mean fubini? but dom. convergence would work aswell or since $\int e^{itx} \le 1$ we can change its order by dom. convergence

Comment: You can use DCT or Funbini.

Comment: but I still do not understand why I need that X and Y are bounded?  What I wrote in the comment above is always true.

Comment: Application of DCT is not that simple. It will not work if $x$ is not restricted to a bounded set.